# Outputting all value descendants from a table when ManyToMany Django ORM

Tags: python, django, database, orm, mptt

There are two tables

```
catalog_product:    
id |name
10  prod3
9   prod2
8   prod1
11  prod5

catalog_productcategory: (mptt model)    
id | name       | lft | rght | tree_id | level | parent_id
2    root1         1     6        1        0      null
3    subroot1      2     5        1        1      2
5    subsubroot1   3     4        1        2      3
6    root2         1     4        2        0      null
7    subroot2      2     3        2        1      6

    
Link table catalog_product_category:    
id | product_id | productcategory_id
7    10           2
8    9            3
9    8            5
10   11           7
```

the catalog_productcategory tree abstract looks like this:

```
root1
  subroot1
    subsubroot1
root2
  subroot2
```

My two models with many-to-many relationship

```
class ProductCategory(MPTTModel):
    """категории продуктов"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)        
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']  


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_products(self):
        return self.category_products.all()


class Product(models.Model):
    """Продукты"""
   
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1024)    
    category = models.ManyToManyField(ProductCategory, related_name="category_products")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

When accessing root1, I want to receive not only products that are in this root category, but also all products that are in child categories, and when accessing a child category, only what is in it.

```
def getiing(request):

    categories = ProductCategory.objects.prefetch_related('category_products')
    stores = []
    for cat in categories:
        products = [{'product_id':  product.id, 'product_name':  product.name} for product in cat.get_products()]
        if not products:
            pass
        else:
            stores.append({'category_id': cat.id, 'category_name': cat.name, 'products': products})

    print(*stores, sep='\n')
```

i get this:

```
{'category_id': 2, 'category_name': 'root1', 'products': [{'product_id': 10, 'product_name': 'prod3'}]}
```

I need:
simple filter by root1:

```
{'category_id': 2, 'category_name': 'root1', 'products': [{'product_id': 10, 'product_name': 'prod3'}, {'product_id': 9, 'product_name': 'prod2'}, {'product_id': 8, 'product_name': 'prod1'}]}
```

simple filter by subroot1:

```
{'category_id': 3, 'category_name': 'subroot1', 'products': [{'product_id': 10, 'product_name': 'prod3'}, {'product_id': 9, 'product_name': 'prod2'}]}
```

Category nesting level unlimited

Answer (score 0):

what i needed

```
    Product.objects.filter(category__in=ProductCategory.objects.get(id=5).
get_descendants(include_self=True))
```